# installing scipy on Python2.7 on a centos 6.4 OS

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos

I'm trying to install scipy on Python 2.7 installed on a CentOS 6.4 OS. This python version is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7 . There is also a Python2.6 on this machine because of CentOS.

For some reason, while yum can install very python package I want into Python2.7 (from BioPython to NumPy), it won't install SciPy into Python2.7

Downloading the tar file from scipy, I can't use setup.py to install to this location. Any idea how I can get scipy on Python2.7? It seems like a directory issue, but just for scipy and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How are you getting yum to install python 2.7 packages? Do you have an extra repo added with them? Or one of the new SCL repos set up?

Comment: What errors are you getting when trying to install scipy by hand?

Comment: I use the rpmforge repository to install python 2.7 packages.

Comment: Also, when I try to use python2.7 to run the setup.py, I get the following error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

Comment: I'm not a python expert but that looks like a problem with the way scipy calls the `setup` function in `setup.py`. Though why that would be the case I don't know (2.7 compat problem or something maybe). Someone more familiar with python would have to chime in. (Also additional details like that are likely better included in the original post where you can format them sanely.)